# Why aren't my classes being added on button click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm not the best at JavaScript but hope that someone can help me with this.
What i want is that when you press on the one of the buttons, the button gives the div the class open.

I have multiple buttons, so what i mean by this is click on button, button gives content1 the class open, when you press on one of the other buttons the class of that div will be gonna and assign on the other div that button was linked to and so on.

What I now get is that all the open divs stay at the class and didn't get removed. I have tried multiple things like search on google or use other technics but nothing works..

```js
const content1 = document.querySelector('.content1');
const content2 = document.querySelector('.content2');
const content3 = document.querySelector('.content3');

var dn = document.querySelector('.dn');
const one = document.querySelector('.one');
const two = document.querySelector('.two');
const three = document.querySelector('.three');

one.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (dn.classList.contains('open')) {
        dn.classList.remove('open');
    } else {
        content1.classList.add('open');
    }
})

two.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (dn.classList.contains('open')) {
        dn.classList.remove('open');
    } else {
        content2.classList.add('open');
    }
})

three.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (dn.classList.contains('open')) {
        dn.classList.remove('open');
    } else {
        content3.classList.add('open');
    }
})
```

```css
.dn {
    display: none;
}
.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainBOX" class="mainBOX">
    <button class="btn one">btn1</button>
    <button class="btn two">btn2</button>
    <button class="btn three">btn3</button>

    <div class="dn content1">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="dn content2">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum2</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="dn content3">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum3</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should use event delegation on the div. Many events slow down the page reactivity. Furthermore you have to refactore the code : use a cycle.  However the problem could be that you run the script js before in the head when the button stll doesn't exist

Comment: You could replicate your problem with two or three buttons. This many buttons just adds noise to your question.

Comment: It's also unclear what the expected behavior. Long paragraphs are hard, bullet items of actual steps vs expected steps is much simpler. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: it will be better if you use the `forEach()` method, given the same class for the buttons

Comment: What in your console?Press F12, go in the console and put here

Comment: Are you aware that `var dn = document.querySelector('.dn');` returns just the first element? Not sure why you would add the class to all elements but act just on the first one

Comment: is this supposed to behave like an accordion/ tab panel? The currently clicked button's div should be visible?

Comment: Welcome, and please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you you are trying to make sure that the current clicked item becomes open, you need to first make sure you close all the existing elements matching `.dn`. Your code was only addressing the first one.

Your code was never removing the `open` from any of the divs.

Lastly, two things that will improve your code greatly:

- Event delegation: so that you only need a single handler
- Using data attributes to associate buttons with their divs (someone else suggested using index which is OK but most people try to stay away from parallel arrays)

```js
document.getElementById('mainBOX').addEventListener('click', (e)=> {
    // Ignore clicks not on buttons
    if (e.target.tagName !== 'BUTTON') {
       return;
    }
    // Close all divs
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.dn')).forEach(
        dn => dn.classList.remove('open')
    );
    // Open the current one
    document.querySelector('.' + e.target.dataset.for).classList.add('open');

});
```

```css
.dn {
    display: none;
}
.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainBOX" class="mainBOX">
    <button data-for="content1" class="btn">btn1</button>
    <button data-for="content2" class="btn">btn2</button>
    <button data-for="content3" class="btn">btn3</button>

    <div class="dn content1">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="dn content2">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum2</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="dn content3">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum3</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd just target your divs by index:

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
    // get the zero-based index of the clicked element
    let index = $(this).index();

    // hide all divs inside the container and remove the 'open' class
    $('#mainBOX div').hide().removeClass('open'); 

     // show just the div with the right index and add the 'open' class
    $('#mainBOX div').eq(index).show().addClass('open');
});
```

```css
.dn {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-4+XzXVhsDmqanXGHaHvgh1gMQKX40OUvDEBTu8JcmNs="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="mainBOX" class="mainBOX">
    <button class="btn one">btn1</button>
    <button class="btn two">btn2</button>
    <button class="btn three">btn3</button>

    <div class="dn content1">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="dn content2">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum2</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="dn content3">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum3</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

To summarize:

- Use DOM traversal to target elements rather than specific class names
- Use class names to identify sets of like elements
- Don't bother with classes to toggle visibility (unless you want elaborate animations)
- If using jQuery, familiarize yourself with the common methods it provides so you aren't reinventing wheels
- Rather than separate classes for open and not open, just make one the default and apply the other
- **D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself in your code

Answer (score 1):

I have shortened your code using the `forEach()` method and the `toggle()` method for each content.

Was it necessary?

```js
const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
const content = document.querySelectorAll('.dn');

Array.from(btn).forEach(function(btnArray, i) {
  btnArray.addEventListener('click', function() {
  content[i].classList.toggle('open');
  });
});
```

```css
.dn {
    display: none;
}
.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainBOX" class="mainBOX">
    <button class="btn one">btn1</button>
    <button class="btn two">btn2</button>
    <button class="btn three">btn3</button>

    <div class="dn content1">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="dn content2">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum2</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="dn content3">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum3</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looking good, but it leaves multiple elements open simultaneously. I get the impression that this is a tabs/accordion arrangement.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this. Use a forEach function to handle the click event in all buttons with a specific class

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Hide and show</title>

    <style>
      .dn {
        display: none;
      }
      .btn {
        margin-right: 10px;
      }
      .open {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Sample with three contents  -->
    <div id="c1" class="dn content">
      <h1>Content 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="c2" class="dn content">
      <h1>Content 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="c3" class="dn content">
      <h1>Content 3</h1>
    </div>

    <!-- Sample with three buttons -->
    <button id="btn1" class="action-btn">Button 1</button>
    <button id="btn2" class="action-btn">Button 2</button>
    <button id="btn3" class="action-btn">Button 3</button>

    <button id="clean" class="action-btn">Limpiar</button>

    <script>
      const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".action-btn");
      const contents = document.querySelectorAll(".content");

      buttons.forEach(function (item) {
        item.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
          if (item.id === "clean") {
            contents.forEach((item) => item.classList.remove("open")); // Clean all the open classes
          } else {
            contents.forEach((item) => item.classList.remove("open"));
            switch (item.id) {
              case "btn1":
                const c1 = document.getElementById("c1");
                if (!c1.classList.contains("open")) {
                  c1.classList += " open";
                }
                break;
              case "btn2":
                const c2 = document.getElementById("c2");
                if (!c2.classList.contains("open")) {
                  c2.classList += " open";
                }
                break;
              case "btn3":
                const c3 = document.getElementById("c3");
                if (!c3.classList.contains("open")) {
                  c3.classList += " open";
                }
                break;
            }
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I rewrote my contribution from scratch, as I did not read OP requirements properly at first.

Undoubtedly, @isherwood's answer should be the *accepted* one here, as it uses the index of the clicked button and because it uses jQuery which makes the script so much more easy to read!

However, in my contribution I would like to show that the same is also possible without jQuery. Admittedly, it gets a little more complicated:

The whole action happens within an IIFE (`(function(){...})()`) to keep the global name space clean. `mBox` is the `#mainBox` DOM element to which I attach the delegated click event for all `BUTTON`s.

Every time the click event handler is fired it collects all the buttons in `mBox` in the array `btns` (the `[...mBox.SelectorAll()]` construct is necessary to create a JavaScript Array from the collection that is returned by `.querySelectorAll()`).

`odiv` is the (potentially) open div from a previous operation that needs to be closed again by removing the class `open` from it.

Eventually the `open` class gets added to the `div` with the same index as the clicked button in the line

```
mBox.querySelectorAll('div')[btns.indexOf(ev.target)].classList.add('open');
```

By using delegated event listening and by cheching the available `button`s and `div`s after each click it is possible to dynamically add buttons and divs to the page without having to attach event listeners to these elements.

```js
(function(){
  const mBox=document.getElementById('mainBOX');
  mBox.onclick=ev=>{
    const btns=[...mBox.querySelectorAll('button')];
    if (ev.target.tagName=="BUTTON"){
      let odiv=mBox.querySelector('div .open')
      if (odiv) odiv.classList.remove('open');
      mBox.querySelectorAll('div')[btns.indexOf(ev.target)].classList.add('open');
    }
  }
})()
```

```css
.dn   {  display: none; }
.open {  display: block;}
```

```html
<div id="mainBOX" class="mainBOX">
            <button class="btn one">first </button>
            <button class="btn two">second</button>
            <button class="btn three">third</button>
            <button class="btn four">fourth</button>
            <button class="btn five">fifth</button>
            <button class="btn six">sixth</button>
            <button class="btn seven">seventh</button>
            <button class="btn eight">eighth</button>
            <button class="btn nine">nineth</button>
            <button class="btn ten">tenth</button>
            <div class="dn content1">
                <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="dn content2">
                <h1>Lorem Ipsum2</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="dn content3">
                <h1>Lorem Ipsum3</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="dn content4">
                <h1>Lorem Ipsum4</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="dn content5">
                <h1>Lorem Ipsum5</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="dn content6">
                <h1>Lorem Ipsum6</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="dn content7">
                <h1>Lorem Ipsum7</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="dn content8">
                <h1>Lorem Ipsum8</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="dn content9">
                <h1>Lorem Ipsum9</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="dn content10">
                <h1>Lorem Ipsum10</h1>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Code without any explanation as to what the problem was is not very helpful. Especially when it has a hack like `document.querySelector('.content'+ev.target.innerText.substr(3))`

Comment: OK, the remark is justified! Just did not have much time after I finished my "hack" - will deliver explanation!